# Imbalanced dataset: Sklearn and Over | Under | SMOTE sampling?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Is it possible in sklearn to do Over | Under | SMOTE sampling?

If not, is an equivalent technique to apply similar code to `class_weight='balanced` in your classifier?

I've checked the sklearn documentation and I can't seem to find anything on these types of sampling techniques. Any advice would be great.

Comment: There is [`imbalanced-learn`](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/index.html) available which extends the scikit-learn to add different Oversampling and UnderSampling techniques.

Comment: Any advice on why I can't load it despite installing: pip install -U imbalanced-learn? It is saying " No module named 'imblearn' "

Comment: Is the installation process successfully completed? And are you using the same python version, which you used for installing it?

Comment: Thank you Vivek, I had to use pip install and all ok now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vivek Kumar and for your answer which I am posting in the answer section for others to see:

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn